# How to properly handle login from a React Native (Expo) Project Using JWT Token?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-hook-form

As part of my self-learning react-native project using expo I am using a Login component for which the code is reproduced below. The code works fine when the app is run in a web-browser. The JWT token is fetched and stored properly in the local storage and works fine even to fetch user credentials on the next screen(Authuser).
However, when published to expo and run on an android device, the login fails.
Could someone kindly have a look at the code to see where the fault lies. If you think I am jumping ahead of the learning curve, please point to a learning resource! Thanks in anticipation.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Login({navigation}){

  const { register, setValue, handleSubmit, control, reset, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }
  });

  
 

const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    await axios.post('https://example.com/apiLogin.php', data)
    .then(function (response) {   
        if(response) {
          if(response.data.success) {            
            localStorage.setItem('loginToken', response.data.token);
            alert(response.data.message);
            navigation.navigate("Authuser");
          }else{
            alert(response.data.message);
          }
         reset({      
          email: '',
          password: ''
        })

        }

      })      

  }


  const onChange = arg => {
    return {
      value: arg.nativeEvent.text,
    };
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>    
      <Text style={styles.label}>Email</Text>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        render={({field: { onChange, onBlur, value }}) => (
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
            value={value}
          />
        )}
        name="email"
        rules={{ required: true }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.label}>Password</Text>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        render={({field: { onChange, onBlur, value }}) => (
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
            value={value}
          />
        )}
        name="password"
        rules={{ required: true }}
      />    
      <View style={styles.horizonBtnsCtnr}>  
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          color="#5CB85C"
          title="Login"
          onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        />
      </View>      
      
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          color="#FF9912"
          title="Register Here"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")}
        />
      </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Text style={{color: '#5CB85C', textAlign: 'center'}}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("RequestOTP")}>
        Forgot Password? Reset Here!
      </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 20,
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#4E5D6CFF',
  },
  label: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    margin: 10,
    marginLeft: 0,
  },  
  buttonContainer: {
    padding: 10,
  },  
  input: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderColor: '#F0FFF0',
    height: 40,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  horizonBtnsCtnr: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlign: "center",

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

With some more research after posting the question I was able to find a workable solution to the issue. I was wrong assuming that localStorage would work for mobile platform as well.  I should have used AsyncStorage to set and get JWT token.
This is how I solved the problem:

1. I installed AsyncStorage in my expo project using
   import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'.
2. I used AsyncStorage.setItem('loginToken', response.data.token) instead of localStorage.setItem('loginToken', response.data.token).
3. I used const loginToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('loginToken') instead of const loginToken = await localStorage.getItem('loginToken').
   That did the rest. Now I am being able to login from web as well as android simulator and my android phone and being successfully able to fetch the user credentials in authenticated page(s).

Answer (score 0):

To add on top of what @MIK said, if you want to store it in a more secure manner, you're better off using expo-secure-store. This taps into both iOS and Android's native encrypted storing mechanism.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35735013)